# Trouble converting list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, transpose

I have a list that's called my_list and looks like this:

```
$love 
playing working sleeping 
   0.43    0.56     0.88
$will 
otherwise rework rule 
    0.87    0.23  0.11
$new
car  shirt
0.23   0.12
```

I want to convert it to the following dataframe, with the output looking like this:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 
love     playing     0.43
love     working     0.56
love     sleeping    0.88
will     otherwise   0.87
will     rework      0.23
will     rule        0.11
new      car         0.23
new      shirt       0.12
```

I have tried this

```
  df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(cor1,as.data.frame))
```

but then the columns become the default columns of the dataframe:

```
love.playing 0.43 
love.working .56
```

and so on (basically i have only one column with the numbers). 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your list?

Comment: What is `cor1`?

Answer (score 4):

```
out <- stack(my_list)
out$col2 <- row.names(out)
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   values  ind      col2
# 1   0.43 love   playing
# 2   0.56 love   working
# 3   0.88 love  sleeping
# 4   0.87 will otherwise
# 5   0.23 will    rework
# 6   0.11 will      rule
# 7   0.23  new       car
# 8   0.12  new     shirt
```

Reproducible data (please share next time):

```
my_list <- list(
  love = c(playing = 0.43, working = 0.56, sleeping = 0.88),
  will = c(otherwise = 0.87, rework = 0.23, rule = 0.11),
  new = c(car = 0.23, shirt = 0.12)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One `tibble` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map_df(my_list, ~ enframe(., name = "Column2", value = "Column3"), .id = "Column1")

  Column1 Column2   Column3
  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>
1 love    playing      0.43
2 love    working      0.56
3 love    sleeping     0.88
4 will    otherwise    0.87
5 will    rework       0.23
6 will    rule         0.11
7 new     car          0.23
8 new     shirt        0.12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(unlist(my_list)), "[.]")))
df$Column3 <- unlist(my_list)
names(df)[1:2] <- c("Column1", "Column2")
df
#>   Column1   Column2 Column3
#> 1    love   playing    0.43
#> 2    love   working    0.56
#> 3    love  sleeping    0.88
#> 4    will otherwise    0.87
#> 5    will    rework    0.23
#> 6    will      rule    0.11
#> 7     new       car    0.23
#> 8     new     shirt    0.12
```